# non-class template has already been declared as a class template

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, friend

I have cloned a project from GitHub which is implemented targeting Linux (*using Linux specific socket*) to use in windows with VC++.

Have modified the needed part to match windows but compiling the `singleton` class I get the error which I have no clue about and searching similar question did not give me any hint.

> error C2990: 'ISingleton': non-class template has already been declared as a class template

```
Singleton.h
------------
#define SINGLETON_ACCESS friend class ISingleton;
template<class T>
class ISingleton {
protected:
    ISingleton() {}
    static T* mInstance;
public:  virtual ~ISingleton(){}
} /* class ISingleton */
template<class T>
T* ISingleton<T>::mInstance = NULL;
```

and

```
factory.h
-----------
namespace J1939 {
   class J1939Frame;
   class J1939Factory : public ISingleton<J1939Factory> {
     SINGLETON_ACCESS; /* <---Getting Error Here */
     virtual ~J1939Factory();
   private:
     J1939Factory();
/* ..... */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you define `friend` the class `ISingleton`

```
friend class ISingleton;
```

where `ISingleton` is a template class.

```
template<class T>
class ISingleton { /* ... */ };
```

You can't: defining it `friend` you have to specify a template type for it; by example (is what do you want?)

```
friend class ISingleton<J1939Factory>;
```

Comment: Thanks, for explaining, so if other classes also want to use the `ISingleton`  how it should be defined.
I mean I am new to C++ and don't know why after creating a class with extending `ISingleton<J1939Factory>` calling the MACRO will not work

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi - not sure to understand your problem; take in count that `ISingleton` isn't a class but a collection of classes; you can declare `friend` a class, not the full collection; so you have to specify the required template parameters (only a type in this case). I don't understand why you want `ISingleton<something>` `friend`.

Comment: well, I should accept it as the answer instead of calling the Macro, `friend class ISingleton<J1939Factory>;`